# SQL Azure - how to restore a demo database nightly?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We have a sandbox environment for clients to play in and we want to restore the database to a clean state every night.

I have not had any success in finding an example on how to set this up - easy to do this in a local environment using a SQL Agent Job - no idea how to accomplish this in Azure.

Comment: The first thing I thought about - Azure Automation. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/automation/ But I am not sure it the simplest way

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this would be ARM template and a bacpac file. Your ARM template can be deployed with PowerShell or Azure CLI using cron.

Blog Post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2016/03/28/deploy-bacpac-to-azure-sql-database-using-arm/